# How much was Luke's speeder worth?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

In the film "A New Hope", Ben Kenobi promises to pay Han Solo "2,000 now" for passage to Alderaan.

In order to pay this, he tells Luke to sell his speeder.

I assume both Luke and Ben have some modest savings. And, perhaps, they borrowed some credits from someone.

But is it ever stated - or is it possible to work out - how many credits they got for the old X-34?

Comment: "I assume both Luke and Ben have some modest savings."  Why?  What basis is there for that?

Comment: The fact that Luke goes and orders a drink in the canteen. I assume he has some ready cash - even if it's just enough to buy a pint in a sleazy bar.

Comment: If I have a $2000 asset and $12.95 in pocket change, I have $2000.  Luke ran out of his home to chase down R2; he didn't go back to his room to grab his stash.  He may not even have had ID (to whatever extent Tatooine has ID).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the junior novelisation for [*Star Wars: Episode IV: A New Hope*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization)) Luke sold his speeder for 2,000 credits:

> Facing the speeder dealer, Luke said, "All right, give it to me, I'll take it." The speeder dealer, an insectoid alien, had finally agreed to buy Luke's cherished landspeeder for **two thousand credits**.
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Episode IV: A New Hope*: Chapter 7</sub>